Synchronising to nodes in a tree
I’m looking for a way to synchronise different processes which access a tree data structure. When a process acquires a lock to a certain node of the tree, the other processes shall be blocked when they try to access this node or its sub-tree (i.e. all direct or indirect child nodes). The reason is that the data attached to each node depends on the data from its parent nodes, so any write to a node should be mutually exclusive from any other write/read of the node itself or its sub-tree.
The question is: what would be a good “value” (hash) to synchronise to which is the same for a node and any other node of its sub-tree? It’s easy if we have two processes that have the same immediate parent node (in which case they would synchronise to the parent’s id), but I can’t think of any common id (or hash) that identifies a whole sub-tree.
I hope this makes sense and someone can provide some ideas (I looked at Merkle trees, but they don’t seem suitable - or maybe I am missing something).
